How to get the price of the token on Raydium through the contract address of the token?
I'm using the Raydium SDK to implement a few functions, and I'm new to the blockchain space.
I just want to know how to get the current price of a token, which is how much sol a token is currently equal to, from its contract address.
Can someone give a simple code example?

To obtain the price of your token, you can use the Gecko Terminal APIs and DEX scanner APIs. It returns the latest price from the Solanan blockchain.
https://docs.dexscreener.com/api/reference
https://www.geckoterminal.com/dex-api
using Raydium Script:
Calculation of Tocken price (for example SOL-USDC)

I would like to know how to get more accurate data directly from the chain or using raydium sdk

Dexscanner APIs mostly provide accurate data as they fetch the data directly from the chain.

To get through the script using Raydium SDK check edit answer.
